# Are questions about Ubuntu VM's running on other OSes on topic?

Tags: discussion

Are questions about Ubuntu Virtual Machines on topic here? For example: https://superuser.com/questions/1105737/ubuntu-16-on-hyper-v-screen-flicker-and-other-problems. Yes I know that is a SuperUser question but would that be on-topic here?

Comment: Yes they are, running Ubuntu IN a VM is on topic because you are running Ubuntu and running a VM ON Ubuntu is on topic, to an the extent it is about the visualization software and not the guest OS it is running. Take a look at the virtualbox tag, you can find many questions wit Windows or mac host.

Comment: Post an answer then @MarkKirby :)

Comment: I believe that depends on the Q. If it is about settings on the foreign OS regarding vbox and not about Ubuntu itself ... no, off topic.

Comment: I would say it would be Off-topic around here, well, just that one since
A: its Hyper-V which is a windows program, and like Mark said, if it was a Ubuntu VM on Ubuntu then it would be on topic, or Windows/mac guest on Ubuntu host, I worked with Hyper-V and really, that problem is Hyper-V based, not Ubuntu-based :)

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ever here, it really depends on what exactly is asked.

These type of questions would be on-topic when running Ubuntu in a VM with a different host

- Ubuntu in Virtualbox won't boot?
- I have error X when running Ubuntu in a VM
- Grub rescue, Ubuntu VB PLS HELP!!!!

These would be off topic when running Ubuntu in a VM with a different host

- Can't install VB in OSX to run Ubuntu
- Windows problem after installing Ubuntu in Virtualbox

When running Ubuntu as the host, it is sort of flipped, so on topic

- Can't install VB in Ubuntu
- Ubuntu problem after installing Windows in Virtualbox

off topic

- Windows in Virtualbox won't boot, Ubuntu host? I have error X when
- running OSX in a VM with Ubuntu host
- Win 10 recovery screen, in VB on Ubuntu PLS HELP!!!!

So in summery, it is about how much the question is about Ubuntu, OSX crashes in VB with Ubuntu host is off topic because it is an OSX issue but Ubuntu crashes in VB on OSX host is on topic because Ubuntu has the issue.

The question in your example would be on topic here, it is Ubuntu that has a problem, not the Win 10 it is running on.

I hope this helps clear up your confusion a bit.